# ListViews setSelection cancels touch event

Tags: android

Another ListView related problem (gonna kill me someday, I swear).

The situation is following:
I have drag&drop functionality in my app, and the element you are currently dragging can be dropped on the ListView item (kinda like you drag a folder into another folder on PC).

There is also a limited amount of items at the screen at the given time (duh), so I need some kind of scrolling functionality while dragging. The idea is not new, when you drag to top or bottom border of the listview and hold there for a moment, it starts scrolling.

The problem is, when I try to scroll with setSelection, or smoothScrollToPosition the touch event of my draggable view returns with the code 3 (ACTION_CANCELED), so the drag just freezes.

Can anyone help me win this?

P.S. Almost forgot. I tried to use scrollBy. scrollBy doesn't break my touch event, but it doesn't actually scroll listView either. Scrolling goes down, but the items are not recycled and reused again. It just a blank screen where elements must be.